# Prove an inequality involving a root of a quadratic equation

Tags: inequality, polynomials, quadratics

If
$ x=ρ$

is a solution to:
$ x^2  + bx + c = 0 $

Prove that $|ρ|-1<|b|+ |c|$

I tried $$ρ^2 + bρ + c=0$$  with no results.

Comment: x=ρ is a root, i am sorry

Comment: Welcome to Math SE by the way;  Do you mean that,  x=p (the root of that)  or  the root of  x² .. ?  + please, use formatting,  as it's quite difficult reading (without formatting, symbols, etc)   + sorry; but "no results" - what results? (even if the result wasn't expected, tell us what it was, so we can at least, hopefully see some *connection) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ be the solutions to $x^2 + bx + c = 0$. Let's assume, without loss of generality, that $|\rho_1|\geq|\rho_2|$. We shall consider two cases:

(a) If $|\rho_1|<1$, then

$|\rho_2|-1 \leq |\rho_1|-1 < 0 \leq|b|+|c|$.

(b) If $|\rho_1|\geq 1$, it follows from Vieta's formulas and the reverse triangular inequality that

$|b|+|c| = |\rho_1+\rho_2|+|\rho_1\rho_2| 
\geq ||\rho_1|-|\rho_2||+|\rho_1||\rho_2|
= |\rho_1|-|\rho_2|+|\rho_1||\rho_2| \\
= (|\rho_1|-1)(|\rho_2|+1)+1 > (|\rho_1|-1)(|\rho_2|+1) 
\geq |\rho_1|-1 \geq |\rho_2|-1.$

Therefore, in both cases it is true that $|\rho|-1<|b|+|c|$.

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: @PipiGoss If his answer resolves your query, please *accept* his answer by clicking the check mark on the left, below the score awarded for his query.

Comment: +1 to your query - nice.

Comment: @PipiGoss Please, (as user266 said) if this was a solution(it "worked" ? ) Please, show that it did by clicking "accept" as answer,  (the green mark below the voting buttons) :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -c & -b \end{bmatrix}$, then $x^2+bx+c$ is the corresponding characteristic polynomial.

By Gershgorin's theorem, we have $|\rho| \le 1$ or $|\rho+b|\le |c|$,

By reversed triangle inequality, $|\rho| \le 1$ or $|\rho| \le |c| + |b|$,

hence $|\rho| \le \max(1, |b|+|c|) \le 1 + |b|+|c|$